# OpenGL не рисует фигуры в Gtk+ C++

Tags: c++, opengl, gtk

В приложении на Gtk C++ надо вставить окошко, в котором будут отрисовываться фигуры на OpenGL. Вставить это окошко удалось, но кроме изменения цвета фона ничего сделать так и не удалось. Не рисует ни точки, ни фигуры.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <gl/GL.h>
#include <gl/GLU.h>
#include <gtk/gtk.h>;


static gboolean render(GtkGLArea* area, GdkGLContext* context)
{   

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glColor3f(0.25, 0.87, 0.81);
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
    glVertex2f(0.0, 0.0);
    glVertex2f(1.0, 1.0);
    glVertex2f(1.0, 0.0);
    glEnd();

    return TRUE;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    GtkApplication* app;
    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

    GtkWidget* window;
    GtkWidget* gl_area = gtk_gl_area_new();
    GtkWidget* labelTitle, *labelText;
    GtkWidget* vbox;

    window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(window), "GTK + OpenGL");
    gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW(window), 500, 300);

    labelTitle = gtk_label_new("Gtk + OpenGL Application");
    labelText = gtk_label_new("Text label");

    gtk_widget_set_size_request(gl_area, 256, 256);
    g_signal_connect(gl_area, "render", G_CALLBACK(render), NULL);

    vbox = gtk_box_new(GTK_ORIENTATION_VERTICAL, 10);
    gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(vbox), labelTitle, FALSE, FALSE, 5);
    gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(vbox), gl_area, TRUE, FALSE, 5);

    gtk_container_set_border_width(GTK_CONTAINER(window), 10);

    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window), vbox);

    gtk_widget_show_all(window);

    gtk_main();
    return 0;
}
```

Результат:

[image: Выполнение программы]

Что я делаю не так и как заставить OpenGL нарисовать хоть что-то в GTK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для рисования Вы используете opengl второй версии, а Gtk по умолчанию использует версию 3.2 и выше с core profile. Поэтому оно не работает. В документации об этом прямо сказано https://developer.gnome.org/gdk3/stable/GdkGLContext.html#gdk-gl-context-is-legacy

Что делать? использовать туториалы для OpenGL версии 3.2 и старше. Вот должен быть рабочий пример https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gtk/-/blob/master/demos/gtk-demo/glarea.c